# Multiple Rows in same Inset Frame

Tags: graphics, formatting, style

I'm sure this is an easy one, but I would like to know how to put multiple lines of text within the same frame in a graphic Inset. I can't seem to find any examples within the documentation and it keeps not quite working for me.

Relevant Code Snippet:

```
Inset[Framed[
Row[{{"Average Current: ", avgCurrent, 
 " \[Mu]A" }, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints}}], 
Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.85, .9}]]
```

Though this puts both statements on the same line and indepedently wrapped in braces.

I've tried just inserting ",\n," between the two lines but that was no better.

Thanks for any help!

---

In case anyone would like the full plot code i'm using (in case I've missed something important:

```
ListLinePlot[{Ni59s[1], Ni59s[2]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7000}, {0, 25}}, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.75, 0.85], 
AbsoluteThickness[2.5]]}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
Epilog -> {{Dashed, Line[{{1805, 14.5`}, {1869, 21.6`}}]}, {Red, 
AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataNi59s]}, {GrayLevel[.5], 
InfiniteLine[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, 
Inset[Framed[
 Row[{{"Average Current: ", avgCurrent, 
    " \[Mu]A" }, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints}}], 
 Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.85, .9}]]}, 
PlotLabel -> 
"Comparison of Current Yields from Nickel Cathode 59 (Interpolated) \
(Anomolous Points Removed)", 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[LineLegend[{"Cathode 59 - Nickel"}, 
LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.85, 0.45}], 
LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
FrameLabel -> {"Cathode Runtime (minutes)", "Current (\[Mu]A)"}, 
ImageSize -> {850, 550}, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

Comment: Replacing `Row` with `Grid` should do what you want here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Column`:

```
ListLinePlot[{Ni59s[1], Ni59s[2]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7000}, {0, 25}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.75, 0.85], 
AbsoluteThickness[2.5]]}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
Epilog -> {{Dashed, Line[{{1805, 14.5`}, {1869, 21.6`}}]}, {Red, 
AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataNi59s]}, {GrayLevel[.5], 
InfiniteLine[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, 
 Inset[Framed[
 Column[{"Average Current: " <> ToString@avgCurrent <> " \[Mu]A", 
   "Number of Data Points: " <> ToString@noPoints}], 
 Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.85, .9}]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
 "Comparison of Current Yields from Nickel Cathode 59 (Interpolated) \
  (Anomolous Points Removed)", 
  PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[{"Cathode 59 - Nickel"}, 
 LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.85, 0.45}], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {"Cathode Runtime (minutes)", "Current (\[Mu]A)"}, 
 ImageSize -> {850, 550}, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```